# jQuery use two method for one action

Tags: jquery

have one input and use own grid. and use `keypress` for submit value of input, i want to use click on SAVE button and run keypress action.

for example:

```
$('input[name="name"] , #save_button').live('keypress', function(event) {})
```

input must be `keypressed` and `#save_button` must be clicked, can i use this method for running one function to save in database?

sorry for my english.

Comment: live is deprecated, stop using it.

Comment: and keyup is a much better event detector than keypress

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `.live` its deprecated, use `.on` instead.
If you did this

```
 $('input[name="name"] , #save_button').on('keypress click', function() {
     // do something
 });
```

Then if a user clicks on the input, then `//do something` is done as well as if the user clicked the `#save_button`. And if we want users to use the input by clicking on it, then clicking the input should not do the same thing as the `#save_button`. So really these need to be separated into two listeners

```
 $('input[name="name"]').on('keyup', function(e){
        // do something for keyup (use keyup instead, its just better)
 });

 $('#save_button').on('click', function(){
       // do something for click
 });
```

if you want both listeners to do the same thing

```
 function doSomething(){
     // do something for both
 }

 $('input[name="name"]').on('keyup', doSomething);

 $('#save_button').on('click', doSomething);
```

and if you truely need the listeners to "live", then you delegate from the document

```
 function doSomething(){
     // do something for both
 }

 $(document).on('keyup', 'input[name="name"]', doSomething);

 $(document).on('click', '#save_button', doSomething);
```

Also assuming you don't want ALL keypress events to take action but only some keys (like the ENTER key), you may want to take a look at this

http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: thanks @Fresheyball. i get this error `TypeError: $(...).on is not a function`. i'm using jquery-1.8.2

Comment: oh, you should upgrade your jquery to 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Use a named function and use two different events.

```
function myFnc function(event) {}

var doc = $(document);
doc.on("keypress", 'input[name="name"]', myFnc);
doc.on("click", "#save_button", myFnc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two main approaches :

- De-anonymize the handler by giving it a name, then move it to some outer scope accessible to both $(...).on(...) statements (not `.live()`), then attach it by name in those statements.
- Attach the handler as you currently do, and use jQuerys `.trigger()` method to invoke the keypress handler from an anonymous click handler attached to the "save" button.

In both cases you will need to take measures to ensure that `event` passed to the keypress handler is correctly formed such that you avoid an error when the function is triggered from the other event type.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want save your data only after key press

```
var isKeypressed = false;
$('input[name="name"]').on('keypress', function(event) {
isKeypressed   =true;

});

$('#save_button').on('click', function(){
 if(isKeypressed ){
   saveData(); 
 }else{
    // your message
}

});
```

Answer (score -1):

First avoid using live as it is deprecated.
If you are using jQuery 1.7 or greater use `on`.
e.g:

```
var handler = function(e) {
//Handle the event
};
$(document).on( "keypress", 'input[name="name"], #save_button', handler);
```

Comment: That is not how you use on() and you missed the fact the OP wants to use click on the button.

Comment: @epascarello Ah...yep..missed click part of the OP's question